Problema conectar api local c# android studio retrofit
Me encuentro  realizando un ejercicio, y resulta debía conectar una aplicacion de android studio para que consuma una apiweb en c#, sin embargo, no lo logré realizar la conección entre el cliente y la api,  adjunto el código de ambas soluciones .
//defino una interfaz 
public interface IPlaylist {
    //Obtenerplaylist
    @GET("listar")
    Call<List<Playlist>> ObtenerPlayList();

}

// defino una clase con el modelo de datos 
public class Playlist {
    private int Id;
    private String Descripcion ;

    public int getId(){    
        return Id;    
    }

    public void setId(int Id){    
        this.Id=Id;
    }

    public String getDescripcion() {
        return Descripcion;
    }

    public void setDescripcion(String Descripcion) {    
       this. Descripcion = Descripcion;
    }    
}

// tengo la lógica en el main activity 

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  View.OnClickListener{

    public  Button btn_click;    
    public  static  String  direccion="https://localhost:7138/api/";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn_click= findViewById(R.id.btnconsultar);
        btn_click.setOnClickListener(this);    
        listarplaylist();
    }    

    //@Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
       int a=9;
       //listarplaylist();    
    }

public void listarplaylist(){    
    IPlaylist peticion;
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(direccion)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    peticion = retrofit.create(IPlaylist.class);
    Call<List<Playlist>> call=peticion.ObtenerPlayList();    

    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Playlist>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Playlist>> call, Response<List<Playlist>> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                // Procesa la respuesta
                Log.d("API Response", "Success: " + response.body().toString());
            } else {
                // Maneja la respuesta de error del servidor
                Log.e("API Response", "Server Error: " + response.errorBody().toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Playlist>> call, Throwable throwable) {

        }
    });
}



}
  

Depurando el programa, noté que en esta instrucion:
call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Playlist>>() 

se queda en pausa y si lo sigo depurando, salta al final del método y no se ejecuta ni el onRespose() ni tampoco el onFailure  por lo cual no se cual sera el error.
Adjunto el código del  lado del servidor y el modelo de datos  de la api en c#, porfavor ignorar lo que se refiere a la cadena de conexión con la base de datos .
    namespace WebbAppiMusicaDb.Models
    {
        public class Playlist
        { 
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public String Descripcion { get; set; }                
        }
    }

sing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using WebbAppiMusicaDb.Data;
using WebbAppiMusicaDb.Models;

namespace WebbAppiMusicaDb.Controllers
{
  [Route("api/[controller]")]
   
    [ApiController]
    public class PlaylistController : ControllerBase
    {
        // GET: api/<PlaylistController>

        private SqlConnection connection;
        private BaseDatos db;
        public PlaylistController() {
            // instanciamos la base de datos     
          db  = new BaseDatos();
            connection = db.Conexion();
        }

        [HttpGet("listar")]

        public List<Playlist> Enlistar() {             
            var lista = new List<Playlist>();
            lista=  db.Obtenerlista();
            return lista;
        }

        //[HttpPost("Registro")]         
        //public async Task<bool> InsertarPlaylist( Playlist listareproduccion)
        //{
        //    db.insertarPlayList(listareproduccion);                
        //    return  true;
        //}

        // GET api/<PlaylistController>/5 
        // POST api/<PlaylistController> 
        // PUT api/<PlaylistController>/5
        //[HttpPut("{id}")]
        //public void Put(int id, [FromBody] string value)
        //{
        //}

        //// DELETE api/<PlaylistController>/5
        //[HttpDelete("{id}")]
        //public void Delete(int id)
        //{
        //}
    }

Lo que me interesa, es ir probando el metodo listar, sin embargo, en el cliente app de android, nunca me funcionó, en la parte que mencioné lineas arriba, no se si estoy introduciendo mal la url, o falta algo enla configuracion del retrofit, por cierto, si agregué los permisos de internet en el adroidManifest.
He realizado pruebas en postman y el método de la ppi, si me devuelve registros de la base de datos, e incluso con react, pero en este ejercicio no lo logro, se que es algo en en esta parte del código  call.enqueue(new Callback<List>(), que no esta bien, ya que  no entra a los metodos onResponse ni onFailure  y tampoco me arroja ningún error.
